# Finding all points on the line where distance between each of them is dividable by X

Tags: javascript

recently I received ( during job interview) a challange to write a method for finding a largest subset of points where distance between them is dividable by a set number.

example points array is `A =[-3,-2,1,0,8,7,1]`

example number we will be dividing by is 3

so for array above  the biggest subset is [-2,1,7,1]
because:

distance between points is counted as follows abs(A[1] - A[2]) = 3

distance between points 7 and -2 is 9 --> 9 % 3 = 0 so its ok.

I wrote code:

```
var A = [-3, -2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1];
    var biggestArray = [];
    (A).forEach(element => {
        Z=[];
        Z.push(element);
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (element !== A[i]) {
                var distance = Math.abs(element - A[i]);
                if (distance % 3 === 0) {
                    Z.push(A[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        if(Z.length>biggestArray.length){
            biggestArray=Z;
        }
    });
    console.log("biggest Array length:"+biggestArray.length);
    console.log("points: "+biggestArray);
```

For each element from entry array i check its distance with any other element. If it is %3 then I add this point do result array. After each outer loop iteration i check if current result is bigger than last. If yes then I store new one. I receive correct data at least for array given to me.

This task seems to be quite easy ( am I not seeing something?)
Also it will do n^2 operations. Is there any nice way to tone it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that on each iteration you could remove the elements that you include in `Z`, i.e. your first iteration will return `[-3, 0]` so you could remove them from `A`, they will never match anything else. My solution would be:

```js
let input      = [-3, -2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1];
let result     = [];
let workingSet = input;

while (workingSet.length) {
  let first    = workingSet[0];
  let elements = [];
  let unused   = [];
  
  workingSet.forEach( value => {
    if ((value - first) % 3 == 0) {
      elements.push(value);
    } else {
      unused.push(value);
    }  
  });
  
  console.log('elements', elements);
  if (elements.length > result.length)
    result = elements;
  workingSet = unused;
}  
   
console.log('result', result);
```

One note is that you mix old style JS code like `var` with ES6 features like `=>`. I would expect code to either stick to using the older JS style for maximum browser compatibility or to stick to the newer JS style consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The difference of numbers will be a multiple of N if and only if their value mod N is the same. So you can simply group the numbers based on their value mod N, and take the biggest one. This only needs a single pass on the input, which is O(n) complexity instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```js
console.log(largestSubsetWithDistance([-3, -2, 1, 0, 8, 7, 1], 3));

function largestSubsetWithDistance(nums, diff) {
  let result = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let mod = nums[i] % diff;
    if(mod < 0) mod += diff; //Brings negative numbers into the 0 to N-1 range
    if(!result[mod]) result[mod] = [];
    result[mod].push(nums[i]);
  }
  return result.reduce((a,c) => c.length > a.length ? c : a, []);
}
```